# is it possible to provide different images for UIImageView on different size classes

Tags: ios, uiimageview, size-classes

I am developing an universal application with iOS8 size classes. I have a imageview which has to show different images on iPad and iPhone, I don't want to use two imageviews and install each on different size classes or change the image programmatically because I think there should be an easier way.

Thanks in advance
Kind Regards
Ali

Comment: Were you able to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use assest catalog for separate iPhone and iPad images. Add an image to assets catalog and choose attributes inspector on the right side bar and choose the device specific in "Device" tap than you can add different images for iPhone and iPad.You can also add images for different size classes by using width and height in attributes inspector.

I hope this can be help for you.

Comment: I also have to do the same thing but I am not able to find the "device specific". Where it is?